# Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I have ES cluster with 5 machines.
One of that machines is always using more resources than other for instance now i see that average load is CPU 7%, Memory 65,

But i have node4 which is strange because it using 30% of CPU and 86% of memory.

Machines are totally the same, configuration the same only node4 is only data node. And when I compare node4 with other in marvel they are doing almost the same tasks..

Any suggestion how to debug and see why its using more than other?

PS. Reason why i care because few times my cluster dies because of node4, I did some improvements in app, but still i want to understand what is going on with node4.

Comment: Is `node4` the master? Do you have shards on that node that are not on others? Are you sending the search/index requests only to that node? Do you use routing on any of your indices?

Comment: A list of `hot_threads` (`GET /_nodes/hot_threads?threads=1000`) would also be helpful together with node stats (`GET /_nodes/stats`) and the list of shards (`GET /_cat/shards?v`).

Comment: @AndreiStefan Node4 is only data node, and all requests are sent to master (node1, node2) i am not using any routing, amount of shards is 5 on all my 5 nodes

Comment: What's the configuration for your nodes? node4 is data only, what about others?

Comment: node1, node2 they are master/data nodes 3-5 data only.

Comment: Hm. It's wrong to send "all requests are sent to master (node1, node2)"! You should send the requests in round robin fashion to all the nodes holding data.

Comment: And my request with `hot_threads` and nodes stats and list of shards still stands.

Comment: @AndreiStefan https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xf9n2u6ggh92sv7/AABTPmaxqc10eFEyqwrgxxfea?dl=0 i have added responses

Comment: Now i see strange thing that ip from node4, node5 is localhost

Comment: Thank you for pointing me where to write data, it could be first improvement

Comment: You are wasting memory and overall resources by having a lot of small shards... You should consider moving to 1 primary and 1 replica for your indices. The default (5 primaries, 1 replica) is too much.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Add answer about 1 replica one sharrd i will accept it as a solution because i think its first step where i need to start + moving requests to data nodes only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things about your cluster:

- This is wrong: "all requests are sent to master (node1, node2)"! You should send the requests in round robin fashion to all the nodes holding data, otherwise you
  'll have nodes that simply do more work than others
- You are wasting memory and overall resources by having a lot of small shards... You should consider moving to 1 primary and 1 replica for your indices. The default (5 primaries, 1 replica) is too much. Your indices are way too small to have 5 shards.